# Omitting linking verbs

Tags: grammar, phrases, sentence, syntactic-analysis

In the following sentence, is it grammatically correct to omit "being"?

> Cross-reference **[being]** impossible, we must but rely on this sole documentarian, as any other ways of accessing the exclusive, 'unfathomable' truth are absent, or at least unavailable.

What is name of such a construction (e.g. noun-adjective)? Is there a reference where I could look such things up?

Comment: The construction is sometimes called the nominative absolute in English. Its defining characteristic is that it has no finite verb, only a noun and an adjective. The participle *being* is always optional. A more common instance is *that (being) said*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just another form of ellipsis, which is the omission of syntactical elements when the meaning is understood. As such, there's nothing wrong with omitting *being* in a sentence *provided the meaning remains clear*.

The phrase pattern *Absent [noun]* is heard quite a bit:

> Absent evidence, we must conclude the defendant did not commit the crime.

Expanded it might read: "If evidence is absent, we must . . ."